# Do we need i=i as a parameter when using subTest with a for loop?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Is it necessary to write i=i in the example below?
What is the point of writing i=i, when the testing works in both cases(writing it or not):

```
  def test_cart_add_many_items(self):
    for i in [2,3,4]:
      with self.subTest(i=i):
        self.assertEqual(self.cart.add_surfboards(i), f'Successfully added {i} surfboards to cart!')
        self.cart = surfshop.ShoppingCart()
```

I tried looking in the documentaion, but didn't find the required info.

Comment: It's not hidden, I don't know what documentation you were looking at. It [clearly states](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.subTest): *subTest(msg=None, **params) ... msg and params are optional, arbitrary values which are displayed whenever a subtest fails, allowing you to identify them clearly...*

Answer (score 0):

Only if you want `i` in the context (though if you don't, there's probably no reason to use `subTest`)

> Without using a subtest, execution would stop after the first failure, and the error would be less easy to diagnose because the value of `i` wouldn’t be displayed:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests